# awk gsub in perl

Tags: linux, perl, unix

I have file name called test.txt with content as below.

```
cat test.txt
MOD_12345_67890
```

I need to get rid of "MOD_" in the file

I used

```
my $file = `awk '{gsub("MOD_", "");print}' test.txt`;
```

in perl. It removes MOD_ and prints 12345_67890 as expected but there more spaces after the output.

My output statement is

```
my $new_file = $file . ".dat";
print "$new_file";
```

My output should be as follows.

```
12345_67890.dat
```

but i am getting the output as

```
12345_67890
.dat
```

.dat is coming in next line

Can anyone, help me remove the spaces or garbage values after the numbers and output should be 12345_67890.dat

Answer (score 0):

Perl does no processing of its input by default. That means the trailing newline on each input line is still there, unlike in Awk. You need to `chomp` the newline off the input line, or do something like `s/$/.dat/`. Or run Perl with the `-l` option, which will remove newlines from input and add them back on output.

Your question about `gsub` is not very clear. To remove a leading "MOD_", `s/^MOD_//`. To do both substitutions in one expression, `perl -pe 's/^MOD_(.*)$/$1.dat/' test.txt`. The parentheses capture their match into `$1`; additional parentheses create additional backreferences `$2`, `$3`, etc.

Comment: .dat is a print statement.

Not supposed to add .dat to the perl or awk statement.

Just wanted to get rid of the spaces in test.txt

Comment: What you see at end if line is a newline, not spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
$file =~ s/^MOD_//;
```

That will remove "MOD_" from the beginning of the string.  To emulate `awk`'s gsub function as you have written it, do:

```
$file =~ s/MOD_//g;
```

This will remove all occurrences of "MOD_" from anywhere in the string.  There is no reason to use backticks (there is never a reason to use backticks instead of `qx`!) in this case.

Comment: $test.txt is the file which has "MOD_". I need to write the output after removing "MOD_" to $file. How can I do it

Comment: You could always use `Tie::File` (`perldoc tie` for details)

Comment: Or just do `perl -i -pe 's/MOD_//g' test.txt`  (caution, this will modify `test.txt`.)